# Does Python data type are all object based on C Class?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, object, types

I would like to understand precisly what data type are in Python 2.7.
So here is what i understand :

- all types in Python are based on class.
- all the class that Python use are written in C

So when i write this i have:

```
x = 82
```

- Python create an object of the class int
- the class int is written in C
- thus i use a C **long** type in the back

pi = 3.14

- Python create an object of the class float
- the class float is written in C
- thus i use a C **double** type in the back

So there are no primitive Data Type in Python, all Type are object ?

Where can i find the C code that represent the Python class int and float ?

Comment: You can find the Python Mercurial repo [here](https://hg.python.org/)

Comment: Everything, and I mean everything, is an object in Python. There is no primitive data types

Comment: Maybe some classes are written in Python.

Comment: But even if the most common implementation is CPython (Python implementation in C) there are other implementation, notably Jython in which Python objects are translated in ... Java objects or maybe Java intrinsics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python everything is an object: numerics types, modules, functions, lists, dicts, tuples, classes... absolutely everything.

Refer to this for further reading:

https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/

Comment: this article is pure gold ! Thx Simon